# A very minimal IoC container for teaching Inversion of control in Java?

Tags: java, inversion-of-control

I am teaching Java to a very young team. I must introduce them to IoC (inversion of Control).
Starting with Spring is too complex (they know a bit of java right now, and a lot of jdbc under the hood).

I'd like to let them write a simple IoC contianer, but I need a very good example to follow.
I thinked about pico container, but I'd like something very tiny (2-3 class at most).
http://picocontainer.codehaus.org/

Do you know something like that?

Comment: hmmm before starting with a complete IoC container it may be good to give them some examples to make sure they understand the principles of dependency injection and then you can build up from that knowledge

Comment: Yes, my idea is to show pros and cons of IoC, with a simple dependency example. Showing how to do it explicit, and then how to wire it automatically.

Comment: You can do IoC and dependency injection without a container.  I use plain Java code to do my DI construction and wiring of components.

Comment: @Peter Can you provide an example?

Comment: Implemented IOC using service locator pattern in [C_code](https://github.com/shamhub/Design_pattern/tree/master/Service_locator_pattern). That should be a good start to get into java for IOC.

Answer (score 2):

Why not teach using Weld SE?  It's in principle the same as Weld in the J2EE 6+ spec, but the initialisation of the IOC container must be done explicitly in the SE version, and the additional complexity inherent in the web layers can be ignored.

Additionally, Weld is really quite minimalistic, and you can use very minimal examples which don't depend on complex things like having a Servlet Container, and then work it up all the way to a full J2EE multi-tier application if you so desire.

This is also the standards track IOC, and while it doesn't have the market penetration of Spring or Guice, you do get it for free with J2EE 6 containers.

http://seamframework.org/Weld

**Note:** A word of warning, Weld's errors can be unhelpful at times in my experience. Spring provides a much clearer idea of what is wrong when things REALLY blow up.

Comment: Servlet container(tomcat) also works based on IOC, Isn't it? using `web.xml` url pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting with Google Guice. It's more compact than Spring and covers all the hallmarks of good IoC with a minimal amount of code.

You can probably draw heavily on the Guice Getting Started guide for your teaching materials: https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Guice looks great but it seems still too big for my target audience.